# SQL Server: alternative to polling -- call the second post-process storedproc

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, web-services, sql-agent-job

I'm coding a M2M data capture system using SQL Server 2012 and .net 4.5, the scenario is:

I have a remote data capture **app**, a **web service**, a **DB**.

The app captures data and invoke the web service to upload the data to the DB.
The web service call a "insert" storedproc to write raw data directly in Table A; and then, the web service returns a value telling that the insert was successful or not.

Now, a post-process storedproc needs to be run after the insert process to update another table (Table B).
Previously I used 'job agent' but since the required polling interval changed to 'less than 5 minutes', for the efficiency and real-time reason, I want to avoid to use the 'polling'.

Ideally, I want the app to be able to call the web service and get the return message/value, after that, **the DB** fires a stored proc to do the post-process work; the work may take longer so the app doesn't need to wait all the processes are done.

Can I fire the post-process sp from DB side? since the DB knows when the insert is done, and it saves communications from outside the DB.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You might think of using trigger plus Service Broker. In this way, the trigger will send a message to a queue. service broker will be fired to process the message. It decouples your table A update and table B update. If only use trigger to call table B, it will hold your table A update until the table B update finished.